# Preview, Design/Text buttons are missing in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, text, preview

After the Android Studio 3.6 Upgrade the Design/Text button has dissappeared in my layout preview. Preview is not showing up at the right end. Also it is not exist in View --> Tools Windows.
[![https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4Rbi.png][1]][1]

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found it. It is in the top bar, just to the left of the gradle post. 
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRptc.png][1]][1]